# How to handle multiple context within React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React - I am trying to use multiple contexts within my App component, I tried following the official guide on [multiple contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts).

Here is my current code:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import AuthContext from "./AuthContext";
import LayoutContext from "./LayoutContext";
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { auth, layout } = this.props;

    return (
      <LayoutContext.Provider value={layout}>
        <LoadingScreen />
        <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>
          <AuthContext.Consumer>
            {auth => (auth.logged_in ? console.log("logged in") : <Login />)}
          </AuthContext.Consumer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </LayoutContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  logged_in: false
});

export default AuthContext;
```

**LayoutContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const LayoutContext = React.createContext({
  show_loading: false
});

export default LayoutContext;
```

**LoadingScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import LayoutContext from "./LayoutContext";

class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LayoutContext.Consumer>
        {layout =>
          layout.show_loading ? (
            <div id="loading">
              <div id="loading-center">
                <div className="sk-chasing-dots">
                  <div className="sk-child sk-dot1"></div>
                  <div className="sk-child sk-dot2"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : null
        }
      </LayoutContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default LoadingScreen;
```

Following the example, I never really understood how `this.props` (in App.js) could hold my different contexts.

Both `auth` and `layout` show up as undefined, `this.props` is empty, which will in turn cause my app to throw errors such as `Cannot read property 'show_loading' of undefined`

I immediately liked the example provided in the React documentation, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: How are you passing props to your App component?

Comment: I don't really know! The react docs don't mention much about props on the context documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've made a small snippet to show you how you could structure your context providers and consumers.

My `App` component in this case is the root of the app. It has all the providers, along with the value for each one of them. I am not changing this value, but I could if I wanted to.

This then has a single child component, `MyOutsideComponent`, containing all the chained consumers. There are better ways to do this, I just wanted to show you, one by one, how chaining consumers work. In practice you can neatly reduce this using a few techniques.

This `MyOutsideComponent` has the actual component, `MyComponent`, which takes all the context elements and just puts their value on the page. Nothing fancy, the point was to show how the values get passed.

```js
let FirstContext = React.createContext('first');

let SecondContext = React.createContext('second');

let ThirdContext = React.createContext('third');

let FourthContext = React.createContext('fourth');

let MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (<span >{Object.values(props).join(" ")}</span>);
};

let App = (props) => {
  return (
  <FirstContext.Provider value="this is">
    <SecondContext.Provider value="how you">
      <ThirdContext.Provider value="pass context">
        <FourthContext.Provider value="around">
          <MyOutsideComponent />
        </FourthContext.Provider>
      </ThirdContext.Provider>
    </SecondContext.Provider>
  </FirstContext.Provider>
  );
};

let MyOutsideComponent = () => {
    return ( < FirstContext.Consumer >
          {first =>
            (< SecondContext.Consumer >
             {second =>
               (< ThirdContext.Consumer >
                 {third =>
                   (<FourthContext.Consumer >
                     {fourth =>
                      (<MyComponent first={first} second={second} third={third} fourth={fourth} />)
                     }
                   </FourthContext.Consumer>)
                 }
               </ThirdContext.Consumer>)
             }
           </SecondContext.Consumer>)
         }
       </FirstContext.Consumer>);
   }
   
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Now, for the actual explanation. `createContext` gives you two actual components: a `Provider` and `Consumer`. This `Provider`, as you found out, has the value. The `Consumer` takes as child a single function taking one argument, which is your context's value.

This is where the docs are a bit unclear, and a bit which I hope I can help a bit. **This does not get passed automatically in props unless the `Provider` is the direct parent of the component**. You have to do it yourself. So, in the example above, I chained four consumers and then lined them all up in the props of my component.

You've asked about class-based components, this is how it ends up looking like:

```js
let FirstContext = React.createContext('first');

let SecondContext = React.createContext('second');

let ThirdContext = React.createContext('third');

let FourthContext = React.createContext('fourth');

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( < span > {Object.values(this.props).join(" ")} < /span>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FirstContext.Provider value = "this is" >
        <SecondContext.Provider value = "how you" >
          <ThirdContext.Provider value = "pass context" >
            <FourthContext.Provider value = "around" >
              <MyOutsideComponent / >
            </FourthContext.Provider>
          </ThirdContext.Provider >
        </SecondContext.Provider>
      </FirstContext.Provider >
    );
  }
}

class MyOutsideComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FirstContext.Consumer >
        { first => 
          (< SecondContext.Consumer >
            { second =>
              ( < ThirdContext.Consumer >
                {  third =>
                  ( < FourthContext.Consumer >
                    { fourth =>
                      ( < MyComponent first = {first} second={second} third={third} fourth={fourth} />)
                    }
                  </FourthContext.Consumer>)
                }
              </ThirdContext.Consumer>)
            }
          </SecondContext.Consumer>)
        }
      </FirstContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks for writing all of that. Is there any way to pass props to App in a class based component?

Comment: @joao Added a second, entirely class-based example for you :-)